# Multiple SELECT UNION Statements across different tables

Tags: sql

Hey guys please see my current code below:

```
    SELECT a.*, b.Attendance, b.Duration
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2018]) b
  ON a.Game_Code = b.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20180701' AND '20190301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, c.Attendance, c.Duration
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2019]) c
  ON a.Game_Code = c.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20200301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, d.Attendance, d.Duration
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2020]) d
  ON a.Game_Code = d.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20200701' AND '20210301'
```

This code gets me the following result:

[Before Coding Pic]

[image: 1]

I am now wanting to map in more fields (Rush_Att, Rush_Yard) from another table so you can see I added it at the bottom:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Attendance, b.Duration
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2018]) b
  ON a.Game_Code = b.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20180701' AND '20190301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, c.Attendance, c.Duration
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2019]) c
  ON a.Game_Code = c.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20200301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, d.Attendance, d.Duration
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2020]) d
  ON a.Game_Code = d.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20200701' AND '20210301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, e.Rush_Att, e.Rush_Yard
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Team_Code, Game_Code, Rush_Att, Rush_Yard
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[team-game-statistics2018]) e
  ON a.Game_Code = e.Game_Code AND a.[Team Code] = e.Team_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20180701' AND '20190301'
```

When I run this I get the following result:

[After Code Pic]

[image: 2]
You can see that it didn't map over the new columns but rather it mapped in the values to the Attendance and Duration Columns. An Example is the first two records. The Attendance 31007 and duration 193 is correct for this game but the 25 is the Rush_Att number and the 116 is the Rush_Yard number. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it? Thank you ahead of time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Add those 2 columns to your first 3 select statements and either get them from the statistics table or set them to NULL if you don't want those columns for the previous 3 select statements and choose the attendance,duration columns in your last select statement or set them to NULL so that they all align with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want them as separate columns then you need to add them as null to your other union statements like so :

```
SELECT a.*, b.Attendance, b.Duration , NULL as Rush_Att, NULL as Rush_Yard
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2018]) b
  ON a.Game_Code = b.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20180701' AND '20190301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, c.Attendance, c.Duration, NULL as Rush_Att, NULL as Rush_Yard
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2019]) c
  ON a.Game_Code = c.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20190701' AND '20200301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, d.Attendance, d.Duration, NULL as Rush_Att, NULL as Rush_Yard
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Game_Code, Attendance, Duration
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[game-statistics2020]) d
  ON a.Game_Code = d.Game_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20200701' AND '20210301'
UNION
SELECT a.*, NULL as Attendance, NULL as Duration, e.Rush_Att, e.Rush_Yard
  FROM [NCAAF].[dbo].[NCAAF_MASTER_GAME_ODDS] a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Team_Code, Game_Code, Rush_Att, Rush_Yard
  from [NCAAF].[dbo].[team-game-statistics2018]) e
  ON a.Game_Code = e.Game_Code AND a.[Team Code] = e.Team_Code
  WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '20180701' AND '20190301'
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Sorry for the late response. Really appreciate your help on this!